# Youtube channel photo - PHP

Tags: php, json, youtube, youtube-api

Currently I have a script that gives me an array of videos.
The codes below just returns me snippets of the video, but I also want the channel snippets.
Is there an easy method to get the channel picture? 
I'm just looking for a simular method like facebook

//graph.facebook.com/'.DATAID.'/picture?type=square

```
 [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [kind] => youtube#searchResult
                    [etag] => "qQvmwbutd8GSt4eS4lhnzoWBZs0/YQk19vPZKxfDJRuiHi4tP3MnMtk"
                    [id] => Array
                        (
                            [kind] => youtube#video
                            [videoId] => xd0gcrVoocY
                        )

                    [snippet] => Array
                        (
                            [publishedAt] => 2012-12-02T16:06:30.000Z
                            [channelId] => UC9qTKspeA1zG7o5lrl0gwKA
                            [title] => Youtube API: HTML Player mit Youtube Musik (Javascript anfÃ¤nger) [Tutorial] [Teil 1] [1080p] [HD]
                            [description] => Lese die Beschreibung -------------------------------------- Musik - Movement Proposition Â© 2010 Kevin MacLeod Mozilla...
                            [thumbnails] => Array
                                (
                                    [default] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xd0gcrVoocY/default.jpg
                                        )

                                    [medium] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xd0gcrVoocY/mqdefault.jpg
                                        )

                                    [high] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xd0gcrVoocY/hqdefault.jpg
                                        )

                                )

                            [channelTitle] => TitanNano21
                            [liveBroadcastContent] => none
                        )

                )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is collect all the channel ID parameters, then make a subsequent API call to the [channels.list()](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) method. Separate the channel IDs using a comma. Here's a sample API call:

```
part=snippet
id=UCVFIm2xPX2S0nVeTqrsajzg, UCFJbwDv2x97qldmol1cCC6w
fields=items/snippet/thumbnails
```

This HTTP call translates to:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&id=UCVFIm2xPX2S0nVeTqrsajzg%2C+UCFJbwDv2x97qldmol1cCC6w&fields=items%2Fsnippet%2Fthumbnails&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

The response body looks like this:

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "snippet": {
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-D1hJj6pvZC4/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/DUIdrmnUDkM/s88-c-k-no/photo.jpg"
     },
    // etc etc etc
```